# Install the node-osc module in npm, in nodejs

Tags: node.js, installation, package, npm, osc

I'm trying to install the `node-osc` package in nodejs.

I run `npm install node-os`c and get this

I tried installing the dependencies on their own:

```
npm install python
npm install node-gyp
```

This did not work .. any ideas about what went wrong?

[image]

---

Update

---

I have set the environmemtal variable like this:

Variable name: PYTHON
Variable value: c:\Python33\

now I got rid of the python not found thingy and i get this:

[image]

---

### Update

Now I installed the CORRECT verison of python (27) .. 33 is not supported by node-gyp

and I get this:

[image]

---

Update

---

Turns you I had to install some other stuff to get it working on a 64bit machine:

this guide was life-saving:  https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means you're missing Python from your executables, which `node-gyp` requires to build some modules. That means it either isn't installed, or you haven't set the PATH variable for `python`. To fix this, just install Python.

The installation guide states you will need version 2.6/2.7 or above of Python.

Comment: when you say python do you mean the python interpreter or the python node package?

Comment: The Python interpreter. The Node Package Manager requires the Python interpreter to install some modules.

Comment: I installed the correct version now (27) and got over that hurdle.. however now I get something ever weirder.. have a look at the updated question. Thank you anyway for your answer.. It did solve my initial problem..

Comment: Actually I think i will move this problem as a question on its own.